# Но в данном случае истина не видна / невидна

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Но в данном случае истина не видна / невидна.

> Колодец не виден / невиден.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Но в данном случае / истина **не видна.***

*Колодец **не виден.***

**Пояснение**

1. Утвердительная форма  "***невиден, невидна***" обозначена орфографическим словарем **для значения** "***невзрачен, неприметен***".  В остальных случаях выбор делается в пользу отрицания и **раздельного** написания, что видно из практики письма.

Русский орфографический словарь: невидный (недоступный зрению) и невидный; кр. ф. -ден, -дна (**незаметный, невзрачный**)

2. Предикативное наречие ***не видно*** также пишется раздельно: *Истины **не видно**. Колодца **не видно.***
3. В текстах встречается форма "***стал невиден***" в составе именного сказуемого.

**Нацкорпус**

1. Василий Шукшин. Калина красная (1973)

*Склонился, выбрал гаечный ключ — не такой здоровый, а поаккуратней, положил в карман брюк. Покосился — **не виден** он из-под пиджака. Вроде **не виден**.*

2. Герман Садулаев. Таблетка (2008)

*На заре дудки засвистели, и тронулась армия. Шли день, вот Итиль ***стал невиден***. Только малые сёла кругом дороги.*

3. Н. В. Гоголь. Тарас Бульба (1835-1841)

*Балабан отплыл на всех веслах, стал прямо к солнцу и чрез то **сделался невиден** турецкому кораблю.*

4. Елена Хаецкая. Мракобес/ Дорога (1997)

*И хоть **невиден** собой Шальк, а, едва очухавшись, принялся ладно молоть языком, чем и проник в чувствительную душу девушки.*